# Leaving an empty col-md-1 between two columns in Bootstrap for spacing?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, spacing

```
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        Column width of md-4
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1 .d-sm-none">
        <!-- Gap between columns -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        Column width of md-4
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this the right way to space an empty col-md-1 between these two Columns? And hide that on mobile using .d-sm-none. Or is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** you can try this way

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        Column width of md-4
    </div>
    <div class="offset-md-1 col-md-4">
        Column width of md-4
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/hyp84gLu/2/

Comment: Thanks, and that offset-md-1 will only show on medium screens and higher right? So on mobile its gone

Comment: `offset-md-1 will only show on medium screens and higher right?` yes